# iphone download several files

Tags: iphone, download

In my app i need to download several plist.

to download a plist i use the `NSURLconnection`

in my code i use an `UIAlertView` with a `UIActivityIndicator` then when the download is finished i add a button to the alert to dismiss it.

To download the plist i use somewhere in my code an `NSURL` set to the adresse where the plist is, next i set a `NSURLRequest` with the url cache policy and a timeout interval. 
Then i set my `NSMutableData` to the `NSURL` connection with a `NSURLRequest`. 
In the delegate `didReceiveData`: i append data to my mutable data object, in the `didFailWithError:` i handle error. And finaly in the `connectionDidFinishLoading`  i serialize my data to a plist so i can write to file my plist, and release my alertview.

My problem is : how can i do if i have sevetal file to download because the `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called each time my `NSURLConnection` is finished but i want to release my `UiAlert` when everything is finished. But when the first plist is downloaded my code in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` will fire.

here is my code :

in the view did load :

```
// set the UiAlert in the view did load 
NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://adress.com/plist/myPlist.plist"];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
self.plistConnection = [[ NSURLConnection alloc] initwithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediatly:YES];
//plistConnection is a NSURLConnection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data { 
[incomingPListData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connectionDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

// handle error here 
}

-(void)connectionDidFinisloading:(NSURLConnection *) connection { 
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *serialErrorString; 

NSData *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialisation propertyListFromData:incomingPlistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&serialErrorString];

if (serialErrorString) {//error}
else { // create path and write plist to path}
// change message and title of the alert
```

so if i want todownload an another file  where do i put the request the connection and how can i tell the `didFinishLoading` to fire code when all my file are downloaded.

thanks to all

Comment: sorry not to quote code but i'm on a smart phone

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over an array of resources you wish to download, and allocate a request for each of them. It is possible to set a tag to a connection (e.g. the index of the URL in the array) which you can evaluate in the connectionDidFinishLoading. If you hold the information, which requests are sent and which are finished, you can easily see, if all files have been loaded.

Comment: i do no understand but thank you i ll search the web 
may be you can give me an example sorry but i'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

I think unset provided a good answer. I understand that you don't get it (you will someday), as I remember myself being new to programming and such.

I therefore provide another, much simpler option to evaluate if all downloads did finish.

you simply use a counter that you define in your .h file,

```
int activeDownloads;
```

in your implementation (.m) File, wherever you start all your downloads, set `activeDownloads` to zero before any of your downloads start

```
 activeDownloads = 0;
```

before you start a download you increase the number of activeDownloads

```
++activeDownloads;
```

if a download finishes or fails you decrease the same countervariable

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection { --activeDownloads;}
```

(i didn't write down the method that gets called if a download fails...

also everytime a connection finishes or fails you have to check if the one that finished or railed was the last one. 
you do that by simply checking if `activeDownloads` is equal to zero. If that is the case, you can add the "close" Button to your AlertView.

The drawback of this solution is, that you're unable to track which connection succeeded and which failed. (well, you are, but `activeDownloads` don't help you with that)

hope i could help

cheers

Comment: ok thanks i've understand but how can i start another download ?? because if i add another NSURLConnection the app crashes. 
i do not understand hiw to add another download